# Piece wise Polynomial Regression

Tags: regression, splines, interpolation

It's wide known that for polynomial interpolation Chebyshev sites (as knots) are almost optimal, we can show that using those the Lebesgue constant is near to the lower bound. 
Is that claim also valid for piece wise polynomial regression? this is, by setting the break points in the Chebyshev sites, do I obtain an analogous result regarding the optimality of the estimation? If yes, is there any form to prove that, for instance some analogous of the Lebesgue function/constant in the regression framework?
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same as your previous question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/387128/spline-regression-are-chebyshev-sites-good-as-knots?  Splines, after all, are piecewise polynomials.  Is the difference between them (namely the constraints to match the splines) really substantial enough to warrant two questions about this topic?

Comment: I was basically re expressing the question in more friendly terms in order to increase the probability of receiving an answer. I didn't know that it was against the policies of the site to do that

Comment: It's not against our policies to re-express an unanswered question--but you can do that simply by editing the original.  This keeps the site much cleaner.  For some suggestions for getting answers, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers.